# Best practice to delay thread without impacting performance or preventing memory leak?

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, thread-safety, quartz.net

In my application, Currently running the background tasks using the quartz.net library in the .net core. We will be deploying in Kubernetes and at least 2 pods will be running.

To prevent the same job from running I am using distributed lock [library](https://github.com/madelson/DistributedLock) where one pod will be acquiring the lock and the remaining pod will be waiting until another pod leaves the lock.

```
while (true) {

  var killingToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
  try {
    Console.WriteLine("Trying to acquire the lock");
    using
    var handle = await @lock.TryAcquireAsync();
    if (handle != null) {

      handle.HandleLostToken.Register(async () => {
        await StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        killingToken.Cancel();
      });

      jobMetadatas?.ForEach(jobMetadata => {
        IJobDetail jobDetail = CreateJob(jobMetadata, handle);
        ITrigger trigger = CreateTrigger(jobMetadata);
        Scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger, cancellationToken).GetAwaiter();
      });

      await Scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);

      Task.Delay(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, killingToken.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    } else {

      Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} not acquired lock");
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    killingToken.Cancel();
  }
}
```

So in the above code, the variable "handle" will be having the lock until the variable handle dispose.

```
using var handle = await @lock.TryAcquireAsync();
```

To prevent the dispose of handle variable. I am delaying the thread with the following statement.

```
Task.Delay(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, killingToken.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Is there any better way in handling the following case? Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.